# Multiple lines in a table cell in the second column

Tags: tables

I have the following:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| l | l |}
\hline
\cellcolor{lightgray}Ligand & \cellcolor{lightgray}Residue Changes\\
\hline
Olmesartan & {19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\ Changed Lys326 to a Gly}\\
\hline
Losartan & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance}\\
\hline
Result \#1 & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance}\\
\hline
Result \#6 & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance}\\
\hline
Result \#7 & {19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\ TK}\\
\hline
Result \#16 & {19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\TK}\\
\hline
Result \#24 & {19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\ TK}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Protein Structural Changes}
\label{tab:structureChanges}
\end{table}
```

And my output is:
[image]

But I want the 'TK' to be in the second column, not the first.  Can someone help?

Comment: You need to take care to enter all cell separators `&` correctly. Also, groups (enclosed with `{}`) cannot span across cells (at least not in a traditional `tabular`). The code for the second and third row should read `Olmesartan & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\ Changed Lys326 to a Gly & \\ `.

Comment: If you want "TK" to be in the second column, the code for the seventh and eighth row should probably read `Result \#7 & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\ & TK \\ `. And similarly for the other relevant rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `\\` to insert a line break inside a call. You could use `\newline`, but then you also need to change the column definition to `p{5cm}` (or some other fixed width).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| l | p{5cm} |}
\hline
\cellcolor{lightgray}Ligand & \cellcolor{lightgray}Residue Changes\\
\hline
Olmesartan & { 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \newline Changed Lys326 to a Gly } \\
\hline
Losartan & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\
\hline
Result \#1 & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\
\hline
Result \#6 & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\
\hline
Result \#7 & { 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \newline TK } \\
\hline
Result \#16 & { 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \newline TK } \\
\hline
Result \#24 & { 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \newline TK } \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you could also simply insert new rows and leave the left cell empty (and stick to the `l` column type):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| l | l |}
\hline
\cellcolor{lightgray}Ligand & \cellcolor{lightgray}Residue Changes\\
\hline
Olmesartan & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\ 
    & Changed Lys326 to a Gly \\
\hline
Losartan & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\
\hline
Result \#1 & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\
\hline
Result \#6 & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\
\hline
Result \#7 & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\
    & TK \\
\hline
Result \#16 & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\
    & TK \\
\hline
Result \#24 & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\ 
    & TK \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

I would suggest that you try the `tabularray` package. It allows using your syntax without any further ado:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray, xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{ | l | l | }
\hline\SetRow{bg=lightgray}
Ligand & Residue Changes \\
\hline
Olmesartan & { 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\ Changed Lys326 to a Gly } \\
\hline
Losartan & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance}\\
\hline
Result \#1 & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance}\\
\hline
Result \#6 & 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance}\\
\hline
Result \#7 & { 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\ TK } \\
\hline
Result \#16 & { 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\ TK } \\
\hline
Result \#24 & { 19 Resides from Table \ref{tab:atomDistance} \\ TK } \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]